# Does Z point up or does Y point up?

Tags: aframe

The documentation on the Rotation tag says that Z is vertical (yaw is rotation around the vertical)
https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/rotation.html
But this example
https://codepen.io/bryik/pen/GZLoQv

```html
  <!-- y-roll or "yaw" --> 
  <a-plane id="yaw" material="color: #4CC3D9; side: double" position="0 2 0" rotation="0 45 0" width="2" height="2"></a-plane>
```

Shows that Y points up, not Z.
Is there simply a bug in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks, pushing a fix to the docs for that.

Answer (score 0):

The docs could be bugged, but this really depends on your orientation. (Z is usually yaw)

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-text value="PITCH (X)" color="#333" position="-0.5 5.5 -5"></a-text>
  <a-plane position="0 4 -5" rotation="0 0 0" width="2" height="2" color="blue"><a-animation attribute="rotation"
               dur="800"
               fill="none"
               to="360 0 0"
               repeat="forwards"
               ></a-animation></a-plane>
  <a-text value="YAW (Y)" color="#333" position="-3.5 3.5 -5"></a-text>
  <a-plane position="-3 2 -5" rotation="0 0 0" width="2" height="2" color="green"><a-animation attribute="rotation"
               dur="800"
               fill="none"
               to="0 360 0"
               repeat="forwards"
               ></a-animation></a-plane>
  <a-text value="ROLL (Z)" color="#333" position="2.5 3.5 -5"></a-text>
  <a-plane position="3 2 -5" rotation="0 0 0" width="2" height="2" color="red"><a-animation attribute="rotation"
               dur="800"
               fill="none"
               to="0 0 360"
               repeat="forwards"
               ></a-animation></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/f922j0th/](http://Fiddle)